# display elemenrt of array error

Tags: php, arrays

array in php generate error

```
$array[]= array("usman","ali"); 
     echo $array[0];
```

it return this error
**Notice:** Array to string conversion in D:\xx\xamp\htdocs\array.php on line 2
Array
plz help what wrong with these code of block.but i'm wanted to only create a array and display there element...
these line of code copy from php.net and wroking fine.

```
$array = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");
    echo $array[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
$array[]= array("usman","ali");
```

Doesn't do what you think it does - it will add a new element to the `$array` variable which itself contains an array.

To define a new 1d array try this instead:

```
$array = array("usman","ali");
```

Or you could see the structure of the 2d array you created like this:

```
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array[]= array("usman","ali");
```

You are trying to append to `$array` because of the `[]` brackets at the end.  Remove that and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`$array = array(...)` is overriding  $array with the contents of the new array.

`$array[]= array("usman","ali")` is putting the new array inside  $array[0] (assuming $array is currently empty).  So you would need to do `echo $array[0][0]` to output usman, and `echo $array[0][1]` to output ali.